# Can not pass parameters to REST API WSO2 in JSON format

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Does anyone know about this error?
I'm passing json to the request like:

```
{"param1":"hello world"}
```

**Property Mediator**
action:set,
set action as: expression,
type: string,
expression: json-eval($.param1),
scope: axis2

Seems like API cannot extract the "hello world" value, because logs show:

```
param1=null
```

Works perfectly with value:

```
  <property name="param1" value="HELLO WORLD" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Null this way:

```
 <property name="param1" expression="json-eval($.param1)" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

API Source View:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="REST" context="/api/post">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/createInvoice">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="operation" value="createInvoice" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="operation" expression="get-property('operation')"/>
            <property name="step" value="request"/>
         </log>
         <property name="param1" expression="json-eval($.param1)" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="param2" expression="json-eval($.param2)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="param1" expression="get-property('Axis2','param1')"/>
            <property name="param2" expression="$ctx:param2"/>
         </log>
         <dbreport>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <dsName>OEBS_DS_MOS</dsName>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>call procedure.create_invoice(?,?)</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('Axis2','param1')" type="VARCHAR"/>
               <parameter expression="$ctx:param2" type="VARCHAR"/>
            </statement>
         </dbreport>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"response" : {"code" : "00", "message" : "success"}}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="contentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"response" : {"code" : "02", "message" : "outSeq"}}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"response" : {"code" : "01", "message" : "fail"}}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
      </faultSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: How do you get value of this property to the log?

Comment: @tmoasz Log Mediator -> Property value: expression; Expression: get-property('param1')

Comment: @tmoasz Actually I also pass this parameter the same way to the SQL procedure via DB Report Mediator. DB Procedure gets the empty string as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `scope` of your property.
You set value from JSON to property in `scope="axis2"`, so you can read that property using: `get-property('axis2', 'param1')`, or `$axis2:param1`.

Or you can set property in default scope, and now you can use: `get-property('param1')`, or `$ctx:param1`.

This [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath+) explains it exactly.

Comment: `<property expression="json-eval($.param1)" name="param1"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.param2)" name="param2"
        scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="full" separator="|">
        <property expression="get-property('axis2','param1')" name="param1"/>
        <property expression="$axis2:param2" name="param2"/>
    </log>` still empty string and error _#getNewJsonPayload. Could not determine availability of the JSON input stream.   Error>>> Stream closed_

Comment: same with the scope Synapse(default): null strings and  _#getNewJsonPayload. Could not determine availability of the JSON input stream. Error>>> Stream closed_

Comment: Do you set request header `Content-Type:application/json` in the client you use to send JSON?

Comment: Or your JSON is corrupted, due to this error is from `org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil`. Could have wrong char. Maybe try some other client to send this payload.

Comment: Yeah, Content-Type is set to application/json in Postman

Comment: + HTTP Endpoint `<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ORACLE_REST">
   <http uri-template="http://address/api/post" method="post">
      <suspendOnFailure>
         <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
         <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
         <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
      </markForSuspension>
   </http>
   <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="default"/>
   <property name="contentType" value="application/json" scope="default"/>
</endpoint>`

Comment: also got this as property mediator `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="contentType" scope="default" type="STRING"
    value="application/json" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>`

Comment: `messageType` and `ContentType` should be used in `axis2` scope, like:
`<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>` and 
                `<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>`

Comment: changed scope of messageType and contentType to axis2. No luck. I have added the whole API source to the main post...

Comment: What version of wso2 product do you have? the wso2esb is ancestor of wso2ei

Comment: WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.3.0

Comment: What you get as `Payload` when you log with `level="full"` ?? The error msg: `#getNewJsonPayload. Could not determine availability of the JSON input stream` occurs when there is no payload in body. I suggest to turn on wirelogs to check what wso2 is receiving, and / or use other tool to send that JSON via POST.

Comment: thank you a lot! the problem was with a client. Tried to send request via SoapUI, it worked. **you can set property in default scope, and now you can use: get-property('param1'), or $ctx:param1**  - is the answer to a problem.